# Could someone explain what is wrong with this java code?

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, error-handling, compiler-errors

```
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    int sum;

    sum = sum+i;
}

System.out.println("Sum is " + sum);
```

I'm trying to figure out what is wrong with this piece of code that is supposed to run in java. In VSCode im getting a lot of errors when trying to compile and run it, but I can't seem to understand what is causing the errors.

Comment: what is the initial value of `sum`? Where and when is it initialized? What type is `i`?

Comment: What errors are you getting? Usually those errors got very useful messages in them that tell you what's wrong with your code and what you have to do.

Comment: `sum` needs to be defined outside the loop

Comment: you are trying to access the value of sum before initializing it. You declare it outside the loop, and assign an initial value to it.

Answer (score 2):

`sum` is defined inside the loop, it's only available in that scope.

And `i` variable is not declared, it can be declared just in the loop.

This is a way to fix it:

```
int sum = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    sum = sum + i; // or sum += i;
}

System.out.println("Sum is " + sum);
```

Comment: what about `i`? it is not defined

Comment: `i`is not declared

Comment: true, another bug, I didn't notice. Now it's declared

Comment: One small error with your code is that i is not declared, what do you propose to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

`sum` is declared inside `for` loop. It's scope end inside the loop and you are trying to access it outside the `for` loop and hence the compiler will throw error.